# Need to use SimpleXML and JaxB together

Tags: xml, rest, jaxb, simple-framework

In my scenario, I need to use SimpleXML and JaxB annotations together on an object so that I can use this object to make different kind of REST webservices which we do not want to make any updates.

I have a class below:

```
@Root(strict=false)
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAcessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Patient{

    @Element(name ="id", required = false)
    @XmlElement(name="id")
    private int patno;

    @Element(required = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Element(required = false)
    private String firstName;

// not displaying the getters/setters to save space - but no annotations on those methods.

}
```

I use an object of this class to serialize and send a REST POST request.
The REST service's interface method is annotated as below: (this is outside of my area)

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public StreamingOutput generatePatientData(final Patient patient);
```

Someone else uses my same patient object to do the simple xmlSerialization for another REST service.

But an exception as below occurs:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Duplicate annotation of name 'id' on method 'patno'
```